# SciPy: error on linkage

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Task 
I want to run linkage function on array retrieved from CSV file. Following is the script I am using:

```
r = []
with open('D:\ResultsFiles\mainforspecial.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
     r.append(row)
vals = [line[1:] for line in r[1:]]
varl2 = np.array(vals,dtype=object)
try:
  linkage_matrix = linkage(varl2, "single")
except ValueError,e:
        print "error",e
```

However when I ran this code it gives me an error of "could not convert string to float". I have explored other questions at stackoverflow and found that to resolve this error format of data needs to consider.

Format of val2 is as follows:

```
 [['0' '1' '22','0' '0' '2948']
 ['0' '1' '16', '0' '1' '2945']
 ['0' '2' '19' , '0' '0' '2854']
 ..., 
 ['0' '1' '0' ,'1' '0' '53']
 ['0' '1' '0' , '1' '0' '3498']
 ['0' '21' '9' ,'1' '0' '2878']]
```

Comment: on which line does it raise this error, be specific.

Comment: almost all the lines , this is format of what  each line in file contains completely  `0 1 21 1 1 3 0 7 5 1 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 2 71 23 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2976
0 2 26 0 4 0 0 7 6 0 18 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 5 0 0 2 0 2 3 1 6 0 0 3 80 22 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3074`

Comment: Oh if you are asking about code then it throws error on calling `linkage(varl2,"single")`

Comment: `linkage_matrix = linkage(varl2, "single")` - This line makes very little sense. `linkage`'s first parameter is a condensed distance matrix, `varI2` is not a distance matrix.

Comment: [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) it is mention that it can  **alternatively, a collection of m observation vectors in n dimensions may be passed as an m by n array**. varl2 is array of length m and width n?

Comment: @muhammadharis, yes but still your observations are strings. The basic distance measurements only work on numerical data. If you want to pass strings (probably not, but who knows), you have to pre-calculate the distance matrix with a distance measure of your choice. I guess you may want to convert the strings to numerical values.

Comment: I guess that is not a problem because linkage first try to convert each item into float it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer for future reference:

use `float()` function in python on each item of list/matrix to get exact item number which is causing error. In my case there was one only one row which had one extra `''` at the end.